# How to change email address of a user in devise "safely"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

By default, [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) uses an email address for sign up and sign in.

But I want that the email address should be allowed to be changed by the user.

If I allow the user to edit the email address, and the user specifies an "incorrect" (i.e. a typo by mistake) email address and then user signs out, *and* the user also forgets what the typo'ed email was, now the user account is inaccessible by the user!

How to best work around this? (except for creating a separate, unchangeable username field that will always allow user to login)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can force the user to confirm his account again if he changes his email.

Once, you updated the password of the concerned user, you need to un-confirm the user, and then re-send the confirmation email.

To unconfirm the user :

```
user = User.find(1)
if user.confirmed?
  user.confirmed_at = nil
  user.save(:validate => false)
end
```

To resend the email confirmation :

```
user = User.find(1)
user.send_confirmation_instructions
```

Hope this help !

Answer (score 17):

Devise does this out of the box. Here is the info from the initializer:

```
# If true, requires any email changes to be confirmed (exactly the same way as
# initial account confirmation) to be applied. Requires additional unconfirmed_email
# db field (see migrations). Until confirmed new email is stored in
# unconfirmed email column, and copied to email column on successful confirmation.
config.reconfirmable = true
```

In [confirmable module](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/d5e0171cb40735de8bfc28daa5b6524f7e121732/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb) you may see how it works.

Comment: Most likely it was not implemented in earlier versions of devise (today version is 3.2.2).