# How do I change user status along with Devise actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Rails 4.1 with Devise 3.2.4

I'm using Devise's email confirmation to setup user accounts, but I also need do things after email confirmation such as setup billing information before an account can be considered active.

**How do I manage a user's status along with Devise's mechanism?**

I.e. when a user first signs up, I want their status to be "new". When they confirm their email, I want their status changed to "email_confirmed", and when they submit payment information, I want it to change to "active". I also want to account for when they change their email address -- their status needs to return to "new".

Comment: do you want a user to be able to sign in if his/her email is confirmed but hasn't submit payment information?

Comment: Yes. I'm just wondering where I write my code to customize the devise events.

Answer (score 1):

Devise uses "confirmation_token" field in users table. You can use it to set all of you conditions. You can add a boolean field in users table lets say 'active'(default false). When a new user signs up "confirmation_token" field contains your token so you could check for its not nil condition but we don't need user to be active now so 'active' field will remain false. Now when a user clicks on the link in email, devise changes the "confirmation_token" field to nil so again you could check it but we still don't want the user to be active so your 'active' field will remain false.

Now if you look at devise github repo when a user clicks on the confirmation token in email, your app is redirected to [confirmation controllers show action](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#LC19).

In your case what you can do is redirect the user to your payment information page with a notice saying something like "you need to complete payment information to do transactions" or whatever you may like. You'll have to override [devise after_confirmation_path](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#LC39) method for that something like:

```
# The path used after confirmation.
def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_name, resource)
  if signed_in?(resource_name)
    signed_in_root_path(resource)
  else
    # your payment information page path
  end
end
```

And when user completes the payment information details successfully you can set his/her active field to true and build on from there.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I'm looking for though, because I'm going to have more statuses than just "active". And if the user decides to change their email, how do I change their status at the same time? I'm looking for the way to customize devise, not just work around it.

Comment: if you need more statuses then instead of a boolean field 'active' you can have a string field 'status' and change its value depending on the conditions i described you and for changing the status on email change refer to [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656578/how-to-change-email-address-of-a-user-in-devise-safely)